# C++11: template parameter redefines default argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, default-value

When compiling the following source code with gcc there are no errors / warnings:

```
template< typename T = int > T func( );
template< typename T = int > T func( );
```

When I compile the same source code with clang++, I got the following error:

```
redeftempparam.cc:2:24: error: template parameter redefines default argument
template< typename T = int > T func( );
                       ^
redeftempparam.cc:1:24: note: previous default template argument defined here
template< typename T = int > T func( );
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Command to compile

```
[clang++|g++] -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 redeftempparam.cc
```

(Version information: gcc 4.7.2, clang version 3.3 (trunk 171722))

My question:

Is this type of redefinition allowed?  If not: can you please point me to the appropriate point in the C++ standard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

§14.1.12:

> A template-parameter shall not be given default arguments by two different declarations in the same scope.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T = int> class X;
> template<class T = int> class X { /∗... ∗/ }; // error
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: Which means: It's not allowed and clang++ is correct. Thank you very much!