# C++ object factory with built-in cache - shadows template parameter

Tags: c++, objectfactory

I've a database class which should provide a template method to return repository objects representing tables. Each repository shall exist only once. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333400/how-to-design-a-simple-c-object-factory) example but I want to have an built-in cache.

The `database.h` header looks like this:

```
class Database
{
public:
  Database(const char *connectionString);
  template<typename T> shared_ptr<class T : RepositoryBase> GetRepository();

private:
  sqlite3* _connection;
  map<string, RepositoryBase> _repositoryCache;
};
```

The implementation the `GetRepository` method looks like:

```
template<typename T> shared_ptr<class T : RepositoryBase> Database::GetRepository()
{
  string name = typeid(T).name();

  if(_repositoryCache.count(name) == 0)
  {
    _repositoryCache[name] = shared_ptr<T>(new T(_connection));
  }

  return _repositoryCache[name];
}
```

I would like to call it like that:

```
// SampleRepository is derived from RepositoryBase
shared_ptr<SampleRepository> sampleRepo = GetRepository<SampleRepository>();
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
error : declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter
```

What do I need to change in the template method to not shadowing any template parameter?

---

**UPDATE**

After NathanOliver's suggestions the template method looks like:

```
template<typename T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<RepositoryBase, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> shared_ptr<T> Database::GetRepository()
{
  string name = typeid(T).name();

  if(_repositoryCache.count(name) == 0)
  {
    _repositoryCache[name] = shared_ptr<T>(new T(_connection));
  }

  return _repositoryCache[name]();
}
```

This time I get the error:

```
error : template parameter redefines default argument
```

It points to `nullptr` in the template signature.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried several combinations of the parameters based on the answer given from @NathanOliver. Still I get the error:

```
1>C:\..\Database.cpp(65,98): error : template parameter redefines default argument
1>template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<RepositoryBase, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> std::shared_ptr<T> Database::GetRepository()
1>                                                                                                 ^
1>C:\..\Database.h(25,108) :  note: previous default template argument defined here
1>          template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<RepositoryBase, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> std::shared_ptr<T> GetRepository();
1>                                                                                                           ^
```

For a better understanding I've added the repository base class as well.

```
class RepositoryBase
{
public:
  RepositoryBase(sqlite3* connection);
  virtual string GetTableName() = 0;

  protected:
    sqlite3* _connection;
 };
```

Comment: Is `Database` templated?  If so what does the `template<stuff>` part look like?

Comment: No. It's only the `GetRepository` function templated you can see in the database header file.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `shared_ptr<class T : RepositoryBase>`?  Are you trying to say `T` needs to be derived from `RepositoryBase`?

Comment: `shared_ptr<class T : RepositoryBase>` looks like Java's generics. This in not C++, hence the error.

Comment: + beware of slicing with `map<string, RepositoryBase>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver exactly thats what I try to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
template<typename T> shared_ptr<class T : RepositoryBase> GetRepository();
```

is not valid syntax in C++.  If you want to constrain `T` to be a `RepositoryBase` or derived from `RepositoryBase` then you need to do that in the `template<typename T>` part.  What we do is add a check of the type that `T` is and if that check fails the then compiler will not generate the function which will cause a compiler error.  That would looks like

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<RepositoryBase, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> 
shared_ptr<T> GetRepository();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. To me it looks what I want. I get the following error though: `error : template parameter redefines default argument` and it points to `nullptr` in the template signature. Does the implementation need to look different then in the header defined?

Comment: @BrunoBieri Should look like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ba2e0bad6e9f968

Comment: Thank you for the example code! Still I can't figure it out. I get the error `error : template parameter redefines default argument`. Any hint what this could cause?

Comment: To what I understand it's not allowed by clang to have an header and an implementation which I learned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197544/1306012

Comment: @brunobieri it looks like you are splitting the template code between a header file and CPP file.  You can't do that.