# Entity Component System and multiple components sharing common base type

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, entity-component-system

I'm trying to implement a simple ECS for my game engine. I know that my implementation is not strictly ECS, but I'm refactoring my code to be more component-based. So far I have the following classes:

`Entity`: it is a container of components, and since I want my entity to have multiple components of the same type, it stores them in a 
`std::map<ComponentID,std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>>`. Each component has a unique ID (an unsigned int), that I get from a simple template trick I learned on the web:

A function called GetUniqueComponentID:

```
using ComponentID = unsigned int;

inline ComponentID GetUniqueComponentID()
{
    static ComponentID id = 0;

    return id++;
}
```

contains a counter that simply generates incrementing numbers.
I call this function from a function template called GetComponentID:

```
template <typename T>
ComponentID GetComponentID()
{
    static ComponentID id = GetUniqueComponentID();

    return id;
}
```

this template instantiates a different function for each component that I add to my entity, so code that needs to retrieve a component can index the map using `GetComponentId<Component_type>`, with the concrete component type as the template argument for the function.

The entity class has methods like AddComponent and GetComponent that respectively create a component and add it to the entity, and retrieve a component (if present):

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();
    template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
    T &AddComponent(TArgs&&... args);
    template <typename T>
    bool HasComponent();
    //template <typename T>
    //T &GetComponent();
    template <typename T> 
    std::vector<T*> GetComponents();
    bool IsAlive() { return mIsAlive; }
    void Destroy() { mIsAlive = false; }
private:
    //std::map<ComponentID, std::unique_ptr<Component>> mComponents;              // single component per type
    std::map<ComponentID, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>> mComponents;   // multiple components per type
    bool mIsAlive = true;
};


template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
T &Entity::AddComponent(TArgs&&... args)
{
    T *c = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    std::unique_ptr<Component> component(c);
    component->SetEntity(this);
    mComponents[GetComponentID<T>()].push_back(std::move(component));
    return *c;
}

template <typename T>
bool Entity::HasComponent()  // use bitset (faster)
{
    std::map<ComponentID, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>>::iterator it = mComponents.find(GetComponentID<T>());
    if (it != mComponents.end())
        return true;
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T*> Entity::GetComponents()
{
    std::vector<T*> components;
    for (std::unique_ptr<Component> &component : mComponents[GetComponentID<T>()])
        components.push_back(static_cast<T*>(component.get()));

    return components;
}
```

Since I want to store multiple components of the same type, I store them in a `std::map<ComponentID,std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>>`.

Now my question is:

I need to create a component hierarchy for a type of component: I have a ForceGenerator component that is the (abstract) base class for all kinds of concrete ForceGenerators (Springs, Gravity and so on). So I need to create the concrete components, but I need to use them polymorphically through a pointer to the base class: my physics subsystem needs only be concerned with pointers to the base ForceGenerator, calling its Update() method that takes care of updating forces.

I can't use the current approach, since I call AddComponent with a different type each time I create a specific ForceGenerator component, while I need to store them in the same array (mapped to the component ID of the base ForceGenerator).

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure you know that. I used your same trick for unique identifiers in [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt), but it proved to not work well across boundaries (eg it doesn't work on Windows, it works on GNU/Linux unless you use hidden visibility by default, and so on). Therefore expect troubles if you plan to mix your implementation with shared/static libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use default template arguments like this:

```
class Entity
{
template <typename T,typename StoreAs=T, typename... TArgs>
    T &Entity::AddComponent(TArgs&&... args);
};
template <typename T,typename StoreAs, typename... TArgs>
T &Entity::AddComponent(TArgs&&... args)
{
     T *c = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
     std::unique_ptr<Component> component(c);
     component->SetEntity(this);
     mComponents[GetComponentID<StoreAs()].push_back(std::move(component));
     return *c;
}
```

is called like

```
 entity.AddComponent<T>(...)//Will instatiate AddComponent<T,T,...>
 entity.AddComponent<T,U>(...)//Will instatiate AddComponent<T,U,...>
```

You might even go step further and use some SFINAE to only enable this function when the component can be stored as that type: (Might or might not actually improve the error message)

```
template <typename T,typename StoreAs, typename... TArgs>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<StoreAs,T>,T&> //Return type is `T&`
Entity::AddComponent(TArgs&&... args)
{
     T *c = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
     std::unique_ptr<Component> component(c);
     component->SetEntity(this);
     mComponents[GetComponentID<StoreAs>()].push_back(std::move(component));
     return *c;
}
```

I assume that `Component` is a base class for all components. If you have a finite,known set of components, you can store them in `std::variant<List types here>` instead of unique pointers.

EDIT:
Apparently clang complains: "template parameter redefines default argument". Gcc didn't mind, but just to be correct,  put the `StoreAs` initialization `StoreAs=T` only in Entity class, not to the implementation. I edited the source code.

Comment: I'm not a C++ template guru, is it legal to combine default template arguments and template parameter packs?

Comment: @Luca I am not one either, but gcc nor clang complain about this, I only know that packs must go last and I think default also must go after non-defaults. I edited the answer because clang complained about repeated initialization.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 complains as well, so I put the default template argument in the definition only. I wonder if it is defined by the standard, I can't find any source.

Comment: @Luca working example https://godbolt.org/z/rTQCjz . Note I had to replace is_base_of_v<> with is_base_of<>::value .

Comment: Apparently it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197436/c11-template-parameter-redefines-default-argument .

Comment: I mean, is defining a default template argument before a template parameter pack legal or defined by the standard?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/11900001/default-parameter-template-vs-variadic-template-what-is-the-last-template-para

Comment: Ok, my head is spinning so I take for granted that since the template parameter pack can be deduced it works and it is standard-compliant. Besides, just a few keystrokes and my system works like it should.

Comment: Hold on, that first sentence doesn't mention function templates. So I don't know, but it works on clang and gcc and you got it working in VS, so I would say its correct :)

Answer (score 1):

**NEW PROPOSAL**

Looking at the other answer I got an idea, you can inherit from another CRTP base class for define where to store (only when using mapped store).

Example:

```
//Just for check class
struct StoreAs {};


//Give the store type
template<typename T>
struct StoreAsT : public StoreAs {
    using store_as_type = T;
};

//Some components
struct ComponentA {    };

struct ComponentC {    };

struct ComponentB : public StoreAsT<ComponentC> {    };


//Dummy add
template<typename T>
void Add(T&& cmp) {
    if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<StoreAs, T>) {
        std::cout << "Store as (remap)" << GetComponentID<typename T::store_as_type>() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Store as " << GetComponentID<T>() << std::endl;
    }
}

//Example add
int main() {

    Add(ComponentA {});
    Add(ComponentB {});
    Add(ComponentC {});

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Store as 0
Store as (remap)1
Store as 1
```

**OLD PROPOSAL:**

As a easy approach but quite verbose and not a generic solution you can expand you ID generation trick:

```
template <typename T>
ComponentID GetComponentID()
{
    static ComponentID id = GetUniqueComponentID();

    return id;
}
```

to

```
template <typename T>
struct ComponentIDGenerator {
    static ComponentID GetComponentID() {
        static ComponentID id = GetUniqueComponentID();

        return id;
    }
};
```

Now instead of use GetComponentID you need to use ComponenteIDGenerator::GetComponentID() but now you can create specific specializations.

So, you can specialize to remap some ids:

```
template<>
struct ComponentIDGenerator<SomeForce1> {
    static ComponentID GetComponentID() {
        return ComponentIDGenerator<NotRemappedForceType>::GetComponentID();
    }
};
template<>
struct ComponentIDGenerator<SomeForce2> {
    static ComponentID GetComponentID() {
        return ComponentIDGenerator<NotRemappedForceType>::GetComponentID();
    }
};
```

Now both (SomeFroce1 and SomeForce2) returns the id of "NotRemappedForceType"

and at the end recover the original function:

```
template<typename T>
ComponentID GetComponentID() {
    return ComponentIDGenerator<T>::GetComponentID();
}
```

Comment: I don't mind it being verbose, what I don't like about this approach is that I need to hardcode a class template specialization for each force that I want to add to the system (I don't know how many in advance).

Comment: Updated for add another proposal, inspired by the other answers.

Comment: I like this new proposal more than my answer, because it shift responsibility from caller to the actual component.